# Authorization Required error when accessing Twitter API

Tags: r, twitter

I've found the code below in a tutorial, but after executing this handshake command it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Authorization Required
```

Can you help me to resolve this issue?

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)

        reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
        accessURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
        authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
        consumerKey <- "-----------------"
        consumerSecret <- "-----------------------------"
        twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                         consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                         requestURL=reqURL,
                         accessURL=accessURL,
                         authURL=authURL)
        download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",
          destfile="cacert.pem")
       twitCred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem",
               package = "RCurl"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the CRAN version of twitteR(1.1.7) try using the GitHub version (1.1.8).

The 1.1.8 version useses httr instead of ROAuth which might help
[link](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR)

Download from GitHub:

```
library(devtools)
library(httr)
install_github("twitteR", username = "geoffjentry")
library(twitteR)
```

You might get a Warning message:
Username parameter is deprecated. Please use geoffjentry/twitteR

But you should ind twitteR in your library anyway.

And then with twitteR 1.1.8

```
library(httr)
library(twitteR)
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
tweets <- searchTwitter('#bigdata', n=150) 
tweets.df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(tweets, as.data.frame))
write.csv(tweets.df, "C:/...")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for ur reply... but now it gives me this error

Comment: Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'

Comment: Ok, make sure you have the right credentials. I get the same error if i input a false key in my code. You can try making a new app in twitter. Or ask for new ones in your existing one.

Comment: You can also try cahnging the permissions of your app to :Read, Write and Access direct messages

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are requesting from http and not https for the authURL and accessURL.

Here is some code I use and works:

```
require(twitteR)

api_key = "XXXXX"
api_secret = "XXXXX"

TwitterOAuth<-function(){
  reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
  accessURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
  authURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
  twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=api_key, 
                               consumerSecret=api_secret, 
                               requestURL=reqURL,
                               accessURL=accessURL,
                               authURL=authURL)
  options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))
  twitCred$handshake()
  registerTwitterOAuth(twitCred)
  }

TwitterOAuth()
```

I have some more details in a [blogpost I did a while ago](http://markedmondson.me/how-to-use-r-to-analyse-and-plot-your-twitter-use).

Comment: thanks for ur help::: but it gives this error : Error in TwitterOAuth() : object 'OAuthFactory' not found

Comment: Strange, from a fresh install mine works.  Double check the api key and api secret?  You are putting yours in the above code, right?  And try reinstalling the libraries.

Comment: yup i am putting my api key and api secret